# exporting jasper report in pdf format working but exporting it into html format not working properly

Tags: jasper-reports, jsp-tags

When I am exporting a jasper report in pdf format it is working properly and all the charts are working.  In the case of exporting in HTML format, it is not working properly. The lists are shown but the charts are not coming out in the report. It is showing unnecessary columns with a cross image.

It is not giving any error in the console and after lots of googling I can not find a good answer.

so please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the browser cannot find the image files.

See note in [JRHtmlExporterParameter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporterParameter.html):

"An important issue is images. The HTML format stores images as separate files, so the exporter needs to know where these images will be stored. If they are stored on disk, the IMAGES_URI parameter will be initialized with a string containing the file name on disk. If they remain in memory, IMAGES_URI must point to a resource that is able to send the images to the browser (such as an image servlet, as shown in the webapp example)."